# Fine grained logging configuration for pytest

Tags: python, pytest

When running my [Pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/) based tests, I want to enable debug logging for my own code, but not for 3rd party libraries. For example boto3 gets very noisy if you enable debug logging. According to [the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/logging.html) it is only possible to set the overall log level for all loggers.

Is there a known solution or workaround to use a [logging config file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging-config-fileformat) to define exactly what exactly I want to see?

Comment: Have you tried to create a separate handler for your code? I believe it should be configurable both programmatically or using a config file out of the box, or you can create a hook to add pytest parameter which would control the level for this exact handler

Comment: My code has its own handlers, but that does not help as long as I cannot configure which level to apply to which handler. How to do that in Pytest (without interfering with Pytest and it's logging setup) is my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign log level for any specific module in [yaml file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging-config-fileformat) like this:

```yaml
loggers:
  foo.bar.baz:
    level: INFO
```

Or this:

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    root: DEBUG
    foo.bar.baz: INFO
```

Wildcards supported too.

Comment: You are referring to the docs I linked to?! I know how to configure logging in general, but my question was about pytest and how to use such a file with pytest. Ideally without interfering with Pytest itself.

Comment: My apologies, I read inattentively. Then I think that the key to the solution should be in executing custom code before running tests. Have you tried to force pytest to preconfigure logging in conftest.py with [pytest_configure](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_configure) hook?